# Material UI Date Range Picker not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, daterangepicker, react-datepicker

I went & copied the source code directly from material UI official website: [Website Link](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-picker/)

Installed all the required dependencies. Still the Project was not working. So tried the sandbox link for that snippet on the same official website. [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mb3od0?file=/demo.js)

I am seeing soo many import dependencies error there too:
[image: Code Sandbox from the official website link]

Then tried to install Pickers using their official website link: [Picker Link](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/)

When I am trying to install it using NPM it is giving me an error: `npm i @material-ui/pickers`

I need to implement Date range picker on my project & everywhere i have used MUI as a standard.

How to resolve this? Is there any fix? Is there any working NPM version where I can implement this Date Range Picker on my project using Material UI ? Please help..!

Comment: after installing `dayjs` its working in the sandbox ... not sure what is the issue you are facing

Comment: can you help me with the npm command for `dayjs`, also can you help me with he initial npm command to install this date picker functionality? Will reset everything & try again in a new project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the solution @KcH
The Answer is i have to install `dayjs` dependency & once done this component is working absolutely fine.